# How would I go about proving discontinuity at multiple points for this function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

f : [0,1] -> Reals, $f(x) = x,$ $x\ne 0,$ and $1/x \in \mathbb N.$ Otherwise $f(x) = 0.$

I want to prove that this function is discontinuous at the points 1/n for all Natural Ns.

Initially I thought to do a proof by contradiction by the sequential definition of continuity but I don't think its possible to find infinite sequences that tend to 1/n for each natural n.

In this case do I negate the epsilon-delta definition. But I don't know how to do this exactly as I don't know what to pick for my epsilon and for my x value?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $f$ isn't continuous at 1 for example, it suffices to show that there exists one sequence of real numbers $x_n \in [0,1]$ with $x_n \to 1$, such that

$$lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) \neq f(1)=1$$
Consider for example the sequence $x_n := 1-\frac{1}{n}\in [0,1]$. Note that
$$\frac{1}{x_n} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{\frac{n-1}{n}} = \frac{n}{n-1} = 1 +\frac{1}{n-1}$$
isn't a natural number for every $n\geq 3$. In a similar way, you can show that $f$ isn't continuous at $\frac{1}{n}, n\in \mathbb{N}$.